# Changing segmented control segment background not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Ive added a segmented control to the header of a uitableview. this works fine. but for some reason i cannot make the segmented buttons (or at least just the first button) have a red background color. it just loads with the default silver.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView* NEWview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    NEWview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:78.0/255.0f green:88.0/255.0f blue:74.0/255.0f alpha:1.0]; 
    NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Organisations", @"Events", nil];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(15, 5, 290, 30);
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
    UIColor *newSelectedTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [[[segmentedControl subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:newSelectedTintColor];
    [NEWview addSubview:segmentedControl];
    return NEWview;
}
```

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance for any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tint color for segmentedcontrol works only if segmented control is of bar style.

```
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.tintColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/454) link to changed background color of selected segment

U can also do is set title color slected and not selected like this:

```
NSDictionary *normalAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20.0],UITextAttributeFont,
                                  [UIColor colorWithRed:75.0/255.0 green:75.0/255.0 blue:75.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                  [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                  nil];//[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:  [UIColor redColor]forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
[segmentCtrl setTitleTextAttributes:normalAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSDictionary *selectedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20.0],UITextAttributeFont,
                                    [UIColor redColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                    [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                    [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                    nil] ;//[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:  [UIColor redColor]forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
[segmentCtrl setTitleTextAttributes:selectedAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: This is just the text, i need to change the background of the tabs to red